# How do I hide the red lines of the path following in the game engine?

Tags: game-engine

I have set up path following using logic bricks. Everything works well but I cant hide the red lines in the final game. Also, I cant find anything on the web about these lines. How can I hide/remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the top of the Blender window there should be a menu bar (called the Info Bar) with the drop-down menus for File, Game, Window, etc.

Click on Game, then make sure the option *Show Physics Virtualization* is unchecked. (If you are using the UPBGE fork, go to Game, then click the *Show Debug* option to open another submenu where the option is there.)

This may be the culprit. It can be easy to turn on by accident.

Comment: I have already disabled both. I also have disabled the "visualize" checkbox in the logic block

Comment: After each "scene restart" it re-reads settings and i havent saved them :P done